# Using Case statement in select

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table

```
id     salary

1            100

2            200

3            300

4            400
```

Now I wanted to find the average salary and then compare with each individual salary and then say as *'High'* or *'Low'*.

Whether this can be done with case statement or please suggest me some good way?

My query is

```
select xxxxxxxxxx = 
case 
when(salary>(select avg(salary)from table_name))
then 'High'
when(salary<(select avg(salary)from table_name))
then 'low' 
end;
```

But here my problem is i dont have that xxxxxxxxx column in my table.

is there anyway i can get the value *-'High'* or *'Low'* without adding/Specifying a column in that table to store values?

So please suggest me a solution with using case statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `join`:

```
select tn.*,
       (case when tn.salary > a.avgs then 'High'
             when tn.salary < a.avgs then 'low'
        end)
from table_name tn cross join
     (select avg(salary) as avgs from tn) a;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this.  Here's one option:

```
select id, 
    case when salary > avgsalary then 'High' else 'Low' end 
from yourtable y
   join (select avg(salary) avgsalary from yourtable) y2
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32c64/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.employee_id, 
       A.salary, 
      (CASE WHEN b.ave > A.salary THEN 'LOW' 
            WHEN b.ave=A.salary THEN 'AVERAGE' 
            ELSE 'HIGH' END) remarks 
FROM oehr_employees A,
     (select avg(salary) ave from oehr_employees) b;
```